# twitter update_with_media and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to post updates from heroku using carrierwave to twitter... with media.

http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/API/Tweets#update_with_media-instance_method

I can do it without media, but when I try media, I keep running into problems.

```
Twitter.update_with_media("message", File.new(picture.picture_url.to_s))
```

I get the error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - https://amazonlinktopicture)
```

Any ideas? I  tried with File.open also and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Just for benefit of other

[> Source](https://gist.github.com/koshigoe/1203356)

```
require 'twitter'
require 'open-uri'

config = YAML.load_file('twitter.yml')
Twitter.configure do |c|
  c.consumer_key = config['consumer_key']
  c.consumer_secret = config['consumer_secret']
  c.oauth_token = config['oauth_token']
  c.oauth_token_secret = config['oauth_token_secret']
end

# Tempfile
begin
  uri = URI.parse('https://dev.twitter.com/sites/default/files/images_terms/tweet-display-guidelines-20110405.png')
  media = uri.open
  media.instance_eval("def original_filename; '#{File.basename(uri.path)}'; end")
  p Twitter.update_with_media(Time.now.to_s, media)
rescue => e
  p e
end

# StringIO
begin
  uri = URI.parse('http://a3.twimg.com/a/1315421129/images/logos/twitter_newbird_blue.png')
  media = uri.open
  media.instance_eval("def original_filename; '#{File.basename(uri.path)}'; end")
  p Twitter.update_with_media(Time.now.to_s, media)
rescue => e
  p e
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'open-uri'
Twitter.update_with_media("message", open(picture.picture_url.to_s) {|f| f.read })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
begin    
 twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |c|
  c.consumer_key = config['consumer_key']
  c.consumer_secret = config['consumer_secret']
  c.oauth_token = config['oauth_token']
  c.oauth_token_secret = config['oauth_token_secret']
 end    
twitter_client.update_with_media(message, open(picture.picture_url))
rescue Exception => exc
  @message = exc.message
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
begin    
 twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |client|
 client.consumer_key = config['consumer_key']
 client.consumer_secret = config['consumer_secret']
 client.oauth_token = config['oauth_token']
 client.oauth_token_secret = config['oauth_token_secret']
end    
twitter_client.update_with_media(message, open(picture.picture_url))
rescue Exception => exc
  @message = exc.message
end
```